# $\int_{0}^{1}dx$

Tags: integration

I am really struggling on this $\int_{0}^{1}dx$.

Normally $\int_{0}^{1}xdx=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$ of the i need to replace the values of  $x$ with the limit.

$\int_{0}^{1}dx$, because there is nothing inside the integrand I will asumed that is zero!

Comment: there is a 1 there in the integrand.

Answer (score 2):

$$ dx = 1.dx $$

$$ take \ a \ break, you're \  stressed $$

$$ hehe $$

Comment: Correction, corrected. Should i delete my post?

Answer (score 1):

> Normally $\int_{0}^{1}xdx=\frac{x^2}{2}+c$ of the i need to replace the values of  $x$ with the limit.

By the power rule for integration

$$\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C $$

therefore

$$\int_0^1 x~dx=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^1=\frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$\int_0^1 dx=\int_0^1 1~dx=\int_0^1 x^0~dx=\left[\frac{x^1}{1}\right]_0^1=1$$